# Awk - use particular line again to match with patterns

Tags: awk

Suppose I have file:

```
1Alorem
2ipsuml
3oremip
4sumZAl
5oremip
6sumlor
7emZips
```

I want to split text from lines containing A to lines containing Z match with range:

```
/A/,/Z/ {
print > "rangeX.txt"
}
```

I want this particular input to give me 2 files:

```
1Alorem
2ipsuml
3oremip
4sumZAl
```

and

```
4sumZAl
5oremip
6sumlor
7emZips
```

problem is that line 4 is taken only once ad is matched as end of range, but 2nd range never starts because there is no A in other lines.

Is there a way to try to match line 4 again against all patterns or tell awk that it has to start new range?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Arne pointed out the second section will not be caught but the current pattern. Here is an alternative without the range.

```
awk 'p==0 {p= (~/A/)>0;filenr++} p==1 {print > "range"filenr".txt"; p= (~/Z/)==0; if(!p && ~/A/){filenr++;;p=1; print > "range"filenr".txt"}}' test.txt
```

It also handles more than two sections

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is save the last line of the first range to a variable and then reprint that variable, along with the following range, for the second file.

In other words, since you're just looping through each line, define an empty variable in your BEGIN and then update it each time through. You'll have the variable saved as the last line when your range ends. Write out that line to the next file before you begin again.

Comment: @KarlNordström, how do you mean?

Comment: @KarlNordström, I just added some clarification to my answer, if that helps.

Comment: @KariNordstron, Arne has another working solution. Both approaches should give you your desired result. Thought, like he said, since your example is pretty generic it's hard to know what the best approach is for your specific problem.

Comment: I was thinking about this and it won't help. When I match line 4 with that range, the range won be "active" any more, until I find line with A again. i will have line 4 saved, but no lines 5+

Comment: @JaroslavBucko, it would work, but you would need a second block that detects when a line contains A and Z and on that line you change the current file to print to and print your saved line.

Comment: exactly, the problem is not saving the last line. It is activating the range again. Could you maybe prove your point with some code?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have AWK on my machine or I would. But the other solutions work fine too. You should have something between mine and the other answers to get your code working :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to rematch a record, but writing a variant of the pattern is an option. Here the second range pattern matches from a line containing A and Z to a line containing Z but not A:

```
awk "/A/,/Z/ {print 1, $0} (/A/ && /Z/),(/Z/ && !/A/) {print 2, $0}"
```

prints:

```
1 1Alorem
1 2ipsuml
1 3oremip
1 4sumZAl
2 4sumZAl
2 5oremip
2 6sumlor
2 7emZips
```

As your sample is a bit synthetic I don't know if that solution fits your real problem.